# How to pass data from an utility class to main class in dart

Tags: dart, flutter

I am creating login view in flutter.I created utility class to handle all the api calling.On Tap am able  to make the Api call and also getting the response
successfully.Now the problem is i want to send the response to the main class so that i can parse the data.

```
  Utility.dart:

  Future<dynamic> postRequest(String methodName, var body) async{
 return await http
    .post(Uri.encodeFull(BASE_URL + methodName), body: body, headers: {"Accept":"application/json"})
    .then((http.Response response) {
        print(response.body);
  final int statusCode = response.statusCode;
  print("Response obj: ${response.body}");
  return response.body;
});

 LoginClass.dart:

void _validateInputs() {

   if (_email.isNotEmpty && _passWord.isNotEmpty) {
        if(_connectionStatus!="ConnectivityResult.none"){
         setState(() {
           var stringParams = {"Email": _email, "Password": _passWord};
           Future<User> response = Utility().postRequest(
               "Account/login", stringParams);
         if(reponse.statusCode==200){
          //   Push view to home screen

         }
         });
       }else{
         Utility.showAlertPopup(context, "No Internet", "Please check internet connectivity");
       }
    }  
 }

 class User {

  final int UserID;
  final int UserName;
  User({this.UserID, this.UserName});

 factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
   return User(
      UserID: json['userID'],
      UserName: json['UserName'],
      );
  }
```

M not getting the response back to the login class. What will be the best way to achieve the result.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `await` in order to wait for the response to return, so your _validateInputs() method should be as follows, and you need to add the `setState` after you get the response:

```
 void _validateInputs() async{

   if (_email.isNotEmpty && _passWord.isNotEmpty) {
        if(_connectionStatus!="ConnectivityResult.none"){

           var stringParams = {"Email": _email, "Password": _passWord};
           Future<User> response = await Utility().postRequest(
               "Account/login", stringParams);
               setState((){
                 //add your setState code here, for example remove the loader or something like that
               });
         if(reponse.statusCode==200){
          //   Push view to home screen


         }

       }else{
         Utility.showAlertPopup(context, "No Internet", "Please check internet connectivity");
       }
    }  
 }
```